# InteractiveSize property doesn't change rendered size

Tags: reporting-services, report, bids

I have a simple, one table report in BIDS (SSRS 2008 R2).

Page size is set to: 11in x 8.5in (landscape)

InteractiveSize is set to: 0in by 0in.

The interactive width need to expand so the user can see the whole thing, like the what the developer sees in 'Preview' when designing.

Changing InteractiveSize does nothing for the width when I run or deploy and view the report. Everything I'm finding on the subject is related to trying to display all rows on one page (length) but I am looking to expand the width so the whole report width is seen when rendered on a web page.

Any suggestions would be great.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After an hour or relentless searching on Google... I found that the issue was with compatibility mode being turned off.

The report renders in perfect sizing if compatibility mode for IE10 is turned on.

Still open to a workaround for having the correct view WITHOUT compatibility mode.